# Almost all singular hypersurfaces are reducible?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

Everything is over $\mathbb C$. Let $|\mathcal O_{\mathbb P^n}(d)|$ parametrize all the hypersurfaces of degree $d$ in $\mathbb P^n$ ($n\geq 2$). Let $S\subset |\mathcal O_{\mathbb P^n}(d)|$ be those singular hypersurfaces and $R\subset S$ be those reducible ones (we have this inclusion because hypersurfaces are always connected).

My question is

> Is $R$ open in $S$?

Since singular quadric surfaces are always reducible, I guess for general case almost all singular hypersurfaces are reducible.

Comment: Dear Akatsuki, contrary to what you claim  a singular quadric surface is **not** reducible  in general: think of the singular irreducible cone $x^2+y^2+z^2+t^2=0$ in $\mathbb P^3$ (characteristic of base field ≠2)

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg Why it is singular? Isn't it smooth by Jacobian criterion?

Comment: Dear Akatsuki,  sorry, you are right: I made a typo. What I meant is  that the cone $x^2+y^2+z^2=0$ in $\mathbb P^3$ (with homogeneouscoordinates $x,y,s,t$) is singular at the point with homogeneous cordinates$[x=0:y=0:z=0:t=1]$, and yet it is an irreducible variety. This contradicts your claim that "singular quadratic surfaces are always reducible".

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg Yes you are right. What I wanted to say should be "singular conic curves are reducible".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. For example, plane cubic curves form a $\Bbb P^9$. A well-known result says that the locus of plane curves of degree $d$ with $\delta$ nodes is irreducible of codimension $\delta$ (Eisenbud-Harris give as a reference "Moduli of curves" by Harris-Morrison which I can't check unfortunately). So $S$ is $8$-dimensional. However, the space of cubics decomposing as a line and a conic is open in $R$ and has dimension $2+5 = 7$.

There is a nice discussion (and pictures!) in the book by Harris-Eisenbud *3264 and all that*, starting at page 62.

In general, you can compute easily the dimension of the locus of $R$. I think that $S$ has always codimension $1$, corresponding to hypersurfaces with a single node.

Comment: Dear Nicolas: 1) what you claim about curves with $\delta$ nodes is crtainly not well known and not even correctly stated : what is true is that curves with $\delta$ **singularities** form a subvariety of codimension $\delta$ in the $\mathbb P^N$ of curves of degree $d$ in $\mathbb P^2$. And even that has to be taken with a grain of salt because singularities might coalesce. 2) Indeed the locus of **singular** (not "with a single node")  hypersurfaces of  degree $d$ has codimension one in the projective space of all hypersurfaces of degree $d$ in some projective space $\mathbb P^n$.

Comment: 3) Since Eisenbud and Harris have written two books, let me mention that the one incvoked here is [3264 and All That](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/3264-and-all-that/DC062983CC5F8B7CDD37CFEBCCA5FEA4). [Here](https://scholar.harvard.edu/files/joeharris/files/000-final-3264.pdf) is a free and legal  online  preliminary version. 4) Do you have a reference for the "well known result"  about curves with $\delta$ singularities and especially for the irreducibility statement ?

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg : dear Georges, I am really sorry I took so long to reply. 1) I took the statement from 3264, page 64, stating that plane curves of degree $d$ with exactly $\delta$ nodes has codimension $\delta$ in $\Bbb P^N$, the space of all plane curves of degree $d$. 
2) I think that single nodes hypersurfaces should be an open in the space of all singular hypersurfaces, so they should have the same dimension. 3) You are totally right and I'll edit my answer to mention this. 4) The reference given by Eisenbud & Harris is the book by Harris and Morrison _Moduli of curves_.